# Navigating to a composable using a deeplink with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-deep-link

When a user enters a geo-fence in our app, we show them an offer notification about the area, which when clicked, should direct them to a specific composable screen called `SingleNotification`. I've followed google's [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#4) and their [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks) but I haven't managed to make the navigation to the specific screen work yet. Right now, clicking on the notification or running the `adb shell am start -d “eway://station_offers/date_str/www.test.com/TITLE/CONTENT” -a android.intent.action.VIEW` command, simply opens the app.

The activity is declared as follows in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="station_offers"
                android:scheme="eway" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Our MainNavController class contains the NavHost which in turn contains various NavGraphs. I've only included the relevant graph below:

```
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavigationGraphs.SPLASH_SCREEN.route
        ) {
....
            notificationsNavigation()
....    
    }
```

The notificationsNavigation graph is defined as follows:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.notificationsNavigation() {
    navigation(
        startDestination = Screens.NOTIFICATION_DETAILS.navRoute,
        route = NavigationGraphs.NOTIFICATIONS.route
    ) {
        composable(
            route = "${Screens.NOTIFICATION_DETAILS.navRoute}/{date}/{imageUrl}/{title}/{content}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("date") { type = NavType.StringType },
                navArgument("imageUrl") { type = NavType.StringType },
                navArgument("title") { type = NavType.StringType },
                navArgument("content") { type = NavType.StringType }
            ),
            deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = "eway://${Screens.NOTIFICATION_DETAILS.navRoute}/{date}/{imageUrl}/{title}/{content}"
            })
        ) { backstackEntry ->
            val args = backstackEntry.arguments
            SingleNotification(
                date = args?.getString("date")!!,
                imageUrl = args.getString("imageUrl")!!,
                title = args.getString("title")!!,
                description = args.getString("content")!!
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The `Screes.NOTIFICATION_DETAILS.navRoute` corresponds to the value of `notification_details`.

Inside the geo-fence broadcast receiver, I construct the pending Intent as follows:

```
                        val deepLinkIntent = Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            "eway://station_offers/${
                                offer.date
                            }/${
                                offer.image
                            }/${offer.title}/${offer.content}".toUri(),
                            context,
                            MainActivity::class.java
                        )
                        val deepLinkPendingIntent: PendingIntent =
                            TaskStackBuilder.create(context!!).run {
                                addNextIntentWithParentStack(deepLinkIntent)
                                getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)!!
                            }
                        showNotification(offer.title, offer.content, deepLinkPendingIntent)
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out that the limitations described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72366612/570930) are not entirely true. Specifically,

1. It is possible to deep link from a notification directly into a destination that is inside a nested graph
2. There is no relation between a destination's route and the deepLink URI.

Point 2 above was the key to unlock my understanding of how deeplinks work. They are just arbitrary URIs and have no relationship to the destination's route at all. The rule is that the following 3 items must match up

1. The URI pattern defined in a composable's `navDeepLink` DSL
2. The URI used to construct a `PendingIntent` for the notification
3. The `scheme` and `host` declared in the `intent-filter` in the manifest.

Here are some code snippets. In my case the URIs were static, so you will need to make adjustments in order to address the OP's situation. This example has the following structure

- `LandingScreen` (`"landing_screen_route"`)
- `SecondScreen` (`"second_screen_route"`)
- A nested graph (`"nested_graph_route"`) with a `NestedScreen` (`"nested_destination_route"`)

We are going to see how to reach both `SecondScreen` and `NestedScreen` from a notification.

First, defining the NavGraph using the DSL. Pay special attention to the `navDeepLink` entries here.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppGraph(onNotifyClick: () -> Unit) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "landing_screen_route"
    ) {
        composable("landing_screen_route") {
            LandingScreen {
                navController.navigate("second_screen_route")
            }
        }
        composable(
            route = "second_screen_route",
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink { uriPattern = "myapp://arbitrary_top_level" } // Note that this pattern has no relation to the route itself
            )
        ) {
            SecondScreen {
                navController.navigate("nested_graph_route")
            }
        }
        navigation(
            startDestination = "nested_destination_route",
            route = "nested_graph_route"
        ) {
            composable(
                route = "nested_destination_route",
                deepLinks = listOf(
                    navDeepLink { uriPattern = "myapp://arbitrary_nested" } // Note that this pattern has no relation to the route itself
                )
            ) {
                NestedScreen(onNotifyClick)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, here's how you would construct the PendingIntent for both these cases:

```kotlin
val notNestedIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
    addNextIntentWithParentStack(
        Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            "myapp://arbitrary_top_level".toUri() // <-- Notice this
        )
    )
    getPendingIntent(1234, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}

val nestedIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
    addNextIntentWithParentStack(
        Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            "myapp://arbitrary_nested".toUri() // <-- Notice this
        )
    )
    getPendingIntent(2345, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
```

Finally, here are the `intent-filter` entries in the manifest

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <!--
            The scheme and host must match both of the below:
            1. The navDeepLink declaration
            2. The URI defined in the PendingIntent
         -->
        <data
            android:scheme="myapp"
            android:host="arbitrary_top_level"
        />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <!--
            The scheme and host must match both of the below:
            1. The navDeepLink declaration
            2. The URI defined in the PendingIntent
         -->
        <data
            android:scheme="myapp"
            android:host="arbitrary_nested"
        />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I'm updating the selected answer! You were right, I tested it with nested graphs & navigation arguments, and it works. Nice debugging!

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail It would be helpful if you could edit the answer to also show how to use this with non-static URIs like in your original question

Comment: Thanks, this solution really helped me.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**: Please see @curioustechizen's answer below for the actual solution instead of this workaround!

Alright, after a lot of testing and running the solution of Google's relative code lab a bunch of times line by line, I figured out how to make it work.
First and foremost, it looks like the `host` that we define in the AndroidManifest.xml for the `<data>` tag of the intent filter needs to much the composable destination's route. So in my case, it is defined as:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="notification_details"
                android:scheme="eway" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Second of all, the deep link's uri pattern should match the composable's route format. In this case, since the composable's route is defined as `route = "${Screens.NOTIFICATION_DETAILS.navRoute}/{date}/{imageUrl}/{title}/{content}"`, the correct deep Link `uriPattern`, would be :

```
deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
                    uriPattern =
                        "eway://${Screens.NOTIFICATION_DETAILS.navRoute}/{date}/{imageUrl}/{title}/{content}"
                })
```

Furthermore, the composable destination seems to MUST  be declared inside the `NavHost` itself and not inside a NavGraph. Initially as you can see, I thought that the system would be able to find the destination via the nested NavGraph, but it couldn't (threw a relative exception), so I came to the conclusion that it must be done this way (as is done in the code labs). Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Lastly, I changed the `val uri` definition inside my GeofenceBroadcastReceiver accordingly. Now it looks like so:

```
val uri = "eway://${Screens.NOTIFICATION_DETAILS.navRoute}/${
                                    offer.date.replace(
                                        "/",
                                        "@"
                                    )
                                }/${
                                    offer.image.replace(
                                        "/",
                                        "@"
                                    )
                                }/${offer.title}/${offer.content.replace("/", "@")}".toUri()
```

So to recap, these are the steps that seem to solve this issue as far as my understanding goes:

1. The deep link's destination composable must be a direct child of the main NavHost
2. The AndroidManifest's `android:host` should match the destination composable's route, and lastly,
3. The deep link's Uri pattern should match the destination composable's route (if you use the format `scheme://host/....` you should be fine if you followed number 2)